# Exclude value by the calculation

Tags: matlab

I have an array  A (I have written so as to make it similar to the matrix that I am using) :

%%%%%%%%%%%%% This is Matrix  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
    a = 3; b = 240; c = 10; d = 30; e = 1;
    mtx1 = a.*rand(30,1) + a;
    mtx2 = round((b-c).*rand(30,1));
    mtx3 = round((d-e).*rand(30,1));
    mtx4 = -9999.*ones(30,1);
    A = [mtx1 mtx2 mtx3 mtx4];

for i = 10:12 
  for ii = 17 :19 
    A(i,:)= -9999; 
    A(ii,:)= 999; 
  end
end
```

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

I would calculate some statistical values, **excluding from the calculation the values **-9999** and **999**.

> the statistical values must be calculated with respect to each column.
>   the columns represent respectively: the wind speed, direction, and
>   other parameters

I wrote a code but it is not correct

```
[nr,ncc]=size(A);
for i=1:ncc  

    B = A(:,i); %// Temp Vector
    Oup=1; Odw=1;  %// for Vector Control


     while Oup>0   %// || Odw>0  % Oup>0 OR Odw>0 , Oup>0 && (AND) Odw>0         
         B=sort(B,'descend'); 
         U = find(B<999 & B>-9999); % find for each column of the temp             
                                    %vector
         Oup = length(U);           % Calculates the length
         B(U)=[];                   % Delete values -9999 and 9999

     end
%  calculates parameters with the vector temp
    count(i)=length(B);
    med(i)=mean(B);
    devst(i)=std(B);
    mediana(i)=median(B);
    vari(i)=var(B);
    kurt(i)=kurtosis(B);
    Asimm(i)=skewness(B);
    Interv(i)=range(B);
    Mass(i)=max(B);
    Mini(i)=min(B);

    if length(B)<nr
        B(length(B)+1:nr)=nan;
    end
    C(:,i)=B(:); %//reconstruction of the original matrix
end
```

would you have any suggestions?

Comment: While beeing correct code, I suspect that there is some problem with this line and it is not doing what you want: `for i = 10:12 for ii = 17 :19 A(i,:)= -9999; A(ii,:)= 999; end end` It runs each assignment three times for the same index.

Comment: With your second code block, please describe what it is supposed to do and what it does instead. Especially for the inner while loop, I have no Idea what you intended to implement.

Comment: @Daniel sorry, I rewrote  question

Comment: The code you wrote makes no sense. `A(i,:)= -9999; ` is independent from the inner loop and `A(ii,:)= 999; ` is independent from the outer loop. Maybe you want two separate loops?

Answer (score 1):

If your data set is in `A`, and you want to operate on it with a function `f`, just use logical indexing, i.e.:

```
 f(A( ~(A==999 & A==-9999) )) =...
```

Alternatively, use `find` and linear indexing:

```
 ind = find( ~(A==999 & A==-9999) );
 f(A(ind)) = ....
```

Comment: sorry but I do not have a function
I would like to calculate some values, and as you wrote it is not working.
I did and thought different tests and the loop is tested on vectors where there are no values -9999 and 999

Comment: my answer is generic. You need to understand the value of logical indexing, regardless of if you operate on the data via a function, or in a for-loop. The answer holds because it is general. How to use it depends on your understanding of it.

Comment: @reyryeng  my unique solution is A(A==-9999) =1  ; A(A==999)=1 but... this solution involves an error in the average value calculated for each column